# How to handle InputStream and OutputStream via Bluetooth in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android app that handles an alarm system made with an Arduino.
I have to handle InputStream from the Arduino and OutputStream to Arduino. First, I used a thread to initialize the connection for the Bluetooth socket and it works, but inside the thread I have to call a sort of Service/Thread that could make me handle streams from and to Arduino but I don't know how to do it.
The fact is that the hypothetical service has to listen continuously if there are streams, it has to stop only when I want and not after a certain period of time. Thanks for the help! Here is the code related to the Bluetooth socket connection:

```
    public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.i("Log", "Socket closed");
                    this.interrupt();
                    Log.i("Log", "Thread interrupted");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {

                }
            }

            //I think here I have to start a sort of Service/Thread..
        }
    }
    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
            this.interrupt();
            Log.i("Log", "Thread interrupted");
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar algorithm, that I basically copied from the [BluetoothChatSample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat), that for example comes with android studio samples, too.

You can see all the concepts, how to receive and send a String in the sample and they have added permissions, dialogs to ask the user about enabling Bluetooth and such, too.